# how to calculate this exponential function integral

Tags: integration, statistics

how to integrate this function $$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-z^{2}/2}dz$$, what would the resulting function be, i tried integrating in wolframalpha but it only gave me this solution $\frac{1}{2}\text{erf}(\frac{z}{\sqrt{2}})+c$, erf stands for error function, which i have no idea what it means, can someone show me what the resulting function is going to be, btw this function is for finding area under the standard normal curve

Comment: There's no closed form expression for the cumulative distribution function of the Normal distribution.

Comment: then how do you evaluate it for the z score to get the probability?

Comment: ok let me ask this then instead, having the Z score value how can i compute the probability without referring to the standard normal table? whats the easiest way of calculating this probability?

Answer (score 1):

As Sebastian mentionned, there are no closed form expression for this cdf. Many results in Probabilities and Financial Mathematics (for instance) refer to expressions with the $erf$ function.

Should you be interested in numerically approximating it, you may apply the following classical methods :
 - trapezoidal rule
 - quadrature formulas (Gauss-Lobatto among others)

Unfortunately, they will give you a poor approximation (despite the integrand's regularity) in comparison with the classical tailored approximation mentioned in :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457408/is-there-an-easily-available-implementation-of-erf-for-python

Watch out for the division by '0.' exception though.

Comment: The `erf` function and the complementary error function, `erfc`, are available in most standard math libraries, including C/C++'s [math.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/erf.html) so I wouldn't implement it myself if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Showing that this is, indeed, a density function (integrates to 1 over the whole real axis) is a standard example in multivariate calculus: instead of calculating it, we calculates its square, then changes to polar coordinates, which results in an integral we do can solve:
\begin{eqnarray}
    \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-z^2/2} \; dz \right)^2   \\
     &=& \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2/2} e^{-y^2/2}\; dx dy \\
     &=& \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\infty e^{-r^2/2} r \; dr d\theta  \\
    &=&  2\pi \int_0^{\infty} r e^{-r^2/2} \; dr  \\
    &=&  2\pi \cdot 1 = 2\pi
\end{eqnarray}